# How reuse same CGContext?

Tags: swift, performance, uiimage, cgcontext, uigraphicscontext

Many times each second, I modify an existing UIImage :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 2000, height: 2000), false, 2)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
... do stuff in context...
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I create a new context each time and I need to call image.draw to load the content of the image before modifying it, but image.draw is very time consuming.

is there a way to use the same context along the user session ?

Comment: You don't want to create a UIImage several times a second. You almost certainly want to use two (or more) CALayers for this and not create an image at all. What that means completely depends on what you're doing in "... do stuff in context ..." and what this image is for. (This is a quite large image even on Mac, but not a full screen image, so it's not clear what this is for. It also depends on how many "many times a second" is.)

Comment: If this is for iOS, tvOS, or Catalyst, see also UIGraphicsImageRenderer, which is generally a better choice for this kind of problem. (Though it won't change a lot about your question.) Also, do you really need to make this transparent? That's very expensive. Does the image not fill the context completely?

Answer (score 1):

The drawing process isn't a something to be reused as it `begins` , `draws` , `renders` and finally `ends`  , so every time you need to follow these 4 steps , meaning **Context** is not a heavy created object to be reused